# Android: Passing an arraylist to another activity (Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference)

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm creating a memo app. The "save" button creates a Memo object and adds it into the list (this part works when checked with the Log). 
The "open" view is supposed to send the whole list into the ListActivity, but the whole app crashes when it is clicked on, so for me the issue seems to be with the intent starting the ListActivity (in the MainActivity) or the creation line of the new ArrayList the ListActivity.

There are plenty of questions with a similar problem, but I failed to find many with a code that I can reliably compare to my own. I tried to swap serializables into parcelables and a few other potential fixes, but came back empty handed.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Creating a static instance of this class to access title and message inputs to ListActivity.
    static MainActivity instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        instance = this;

        //Creating the list of memos
        final ArrayList<Memo> memos = new ArrayList<Memo>();

        // Find the View that opens the ListActivity
        TextView open = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.open_view);

// Set a click listener on that View
        open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent openIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                openIntent.putExtra("List_of_memos", memos);
                startActivity(openIntent);
            }
        });

        // Find the View that saves the memo
        TextView save = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.save_view);

// Set a click listener on that View
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                memos.add(new Memo(getmTitle(), getmMessage()));

            }
        });

    }

    //Declaring a method that returns the title value.
    public String getmTitle(){

        //Turning the title input field into a string variable
        EditText titleInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title_input);

        return titleInput.getText().toString();
    }

    //Declaring a method that returns the message value.
    public String getmMessage(){

        //Turning the message input field into a string variable
        EditText messageInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_input);

        return messageInput.getText().toString();
    }

}
```

ListActivity:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    String title = MainActivity.instance.getmTitle();
    String message = MainActivity.instance.getmMessage();

    ArrayList<Memo> memos = (ArrayList<Memo>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("FILES_TO_SEND");

    //Create an ArrayAdapter with a list of Strings as a data source.
    // The adapter knows how to create layouts for each item in the list, using the simple_list_item_1.xml layout.
    // This list item layout contains a single TextView, which the adapter will set to display a single string.
    MemoAdapter adapter = new MemoAdapter(this, memos);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

The object class:

```
public class Memo  implements Serializable {

private String mTitle;
private String mMessage;

// Constructor for the word object
public Memo(String title, String message) {
    mTitle = title;
    mMessage = message;
}

//Get the title
public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

//Get the message
public String getMessage() {
    return mMessage;
}

public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
}

public void setmMessage(String mMessage) {
    this.mMessage = mMessage;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Memo{" +
            "Title='" + mTitle + '\'' +
            ", Message='" + mMessage + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

...and the error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.memo.android.memo, PID: 26543
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.memo.android.memo/com.memo.android.memo.ListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:344)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:556)
                                                                       at com.memo.android.memo.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:29)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2900)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Hope you can help, I've spent quite a few hours without any significant results with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Side comment-  static MainActivity instance;    NEVER DO THIS.  Doing this causes a memory leak.  You should never keep a static reference to an Activity or Service.  If you think you need that, then you have an architecture problem in your application.

Answer (score 1):

In one activity you call the extras "List_of_memos", in the other you call it "FILES_TO_SEND".  The two need to use the same name.

Comment: Hard to recall a time I've been more disappointed in a correct solution. I spent hours trying to figure out some kind of a complex mechanic I was misusing, and it turns out to be an obvious flaw caused by copy/pasting a snipped of code while being tired. Thank you so much for this. =D